# How do I keep a View Controller responding to notifications after it has been dismissed

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view controller that plays audio using MPMoviePlayer. When a song ends it receives a notification and then plays another song. How can I keep the notifications going so the view will continue to respond, even after the view has been dismissed or is popped from its navigation stack?

Comment: You could make a service that is constantly running in the app and detach the actual playing of the song from the view controller(s).

Comment: That's actually kind of what I did. I added an NSTimer that runs when the view is in the background so it keeps going.